# Standard Time and Daylight Time

Tags: java, time, timezone

This is not really a technical programming question, but it has to do with dealing with and displaying time zones in Java.

In the United States, there are time zones like `Eastern Time` and `Pacific Time`, that during Daylight Savings, they are `Eastern Daylight Time` and `Pacific Daylight Time`, while when Daylight Savings is not in effect, they are `Eastern Standard Time` and `Pacific Standard Time`.

So, since Daylight Saving Time starts on the second Sunday of March, and ends on the first Sunday of November, would saying that a date between March and November is in `Eastern Standard Time` or `Pacific Standard Time` be invalid? For example, does the following date technically not exist?

> Tuesday, September 29, 2015 at 10 am PST

Should it not be `Pacific Daylight Time (PDT)`, or just simply `PT` to avoid having to specify `Daylight` or `Standard`?

Comment: I think that is entirely application dependent. What do the users need to see for your application? Is it enough to just show the timezone for them, or do they require more info?

Comment: I don't know about Pacific, but much of Arizona observes Mountain Standard Time year round (no DST), so yes, the date you specified can exist.

Comment: @VGR - PST year round is observed in Metlakatla, Alaska. :)  See http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/pst

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... would saying that a date between March and November is in Eastern Standard Time or Pacific Standard Time be invalid?

If you are talking about a time zone that doesn't observe that particular segment at that particular time, then yes - it's invalid.   Eastern Standard Time is always UTC-5, and Eastern Daylight Time is always UTC-4.  If you say EST when you mean UTC-4, you're using it wrong.  (And people do indeed use it wrong quite often.)

However, as others pointed out, there are locations in many time zones that don't observe daylight saving time, even when the areas around them do.  If you say MST in the summer, it's valid in Phoenix, but not in Los Angeles.

> ... or just simply PT to avoid having to specify Daylight or Standard?

Yes, you can just say `PT` and omit the `S` or the `D`.  It's done often this way on television, but not as often with computers.   Also, that doesn't hold true for time zones over the world (London uses GMT and BST - there is no common generic abbreviation there).

Comment: So if I just say Tuesday, September 29, 10 am PT, how would that be viewed from the position of someone in a locale that observes Daylight Time versus a locale that does not?

Comment: They would interpret it according to their own understanding - which might possibly lead to a different instant in time between two different viewers.  In general though, PT means "PST or PDT, whichever is in effect".   Also consider there will be ambiguity during the fall-back transition, when either might be in effect from 1:00 through 1:59.

Comment: Context is everything.  Consider also that if you said "CT" or "CST" to a worldwide audience, people in China would have a very different understanding than people in the US.

Comment: Hmm, so September 29, 10 am PT in Metlakatla, Alaska would actually be referring to a different instant in time than September 29, 10 am PT in a locale that observes Daylight Time? Interesting...

Comment: Only if the person reading it interpreted it that way.  Don't expect a computer to make such an inference.  Also note that Metlakatla is tiny, so it's likely the locals there would understand that the mainland PT is different from theirs.  However, growing up in Arizona, I know first hand that people there just say "Mountain Time", and often disregard that the rest of MT is in MDT when they are in MST.  A discussion between two people in Phoenix and Denver, people might say "*your* time" or "*my time*", but they would indeed interpret "Mountain Time" differently in the summer.

Answer (score 2):

Saying `EST` for a date/time that is in `EDT`, e.g. July 4th in New York, is invalid, but we humans often don't care and use `EST` loosely. It's wrong but we do it anyway.

In computing, we strive to be exact, so definitely *invalid*.

But VGR was right. Even July 4th can be in "standard" time, if you're in a locality that doesn't observe daylight savings time.

Answer (score 2):

## Proper Time Zone Names

Those names such as "Pacific Daylight Time" are not true time zones. Their 3-4 letter codes are neither standardized nor unique. Do yourself a favor and **forget all about them**. Never use "PDT", "EST", and such in your date-time work.

For date-time work learn to use [proper time zone names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). These are in the format of a continent, a slash, and a city or region. These are not arbitrary or convenient, each represents a history of changes or anomalies with adjustments or definition of that time zone.

So geographical proximity is irrelevant. For example, Seattle is much farther from Los Angeles than is Phoenix. But Seattle’s official time zone is `America/Los_Angeles`, while Arizona uses `America/Phoenix`.

While most of the United States west coast uses `America/Los_Angeles`, not all of it does. As we said Arizona does not, nor does Metlakatla Alaska. But notice how both overlap respectively with the -07:00 and -08:00 offsets used by `America/Los_Angeles` in DST & standard time shifts. (See below)

So you must do your homework to learn what official time zone covers any particular location. If you don't know already in your business logic, you will have to ask the user.

## Use The Framework, Luke

You should not be worrying about when Daylight Saving Time starts and  ends. Use a decent framework for date-time work. Let the framework handle the nitty-gritty details about DST. Your only worry should be keeping the `tz` database fresh in your framework if your zones of interest have changing rules.

### java.time

For Java 8 and later the framework of choice is the new built-in [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)) Inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project.

```
ZoneId zoneId_Montréal = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt_Now_Montréal = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId_Montréal );
String outputNowMontréal = zdt_Now_Montréal.toString( );
```

> outputNowMontréal : 2015-09-04T01:39:46.962-04:00[America/Montreal]

#### Adjusting For DST

[Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) is the most common anomaly in date-time work. When jumping an hour ahead or an hour behind, that means some time-of-day values do not exist at all or occur twice in a day. As the [`ZonedDateTime.of`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#of-int-int-int-int-int-int-int-java.time.ZoneId-) class doc says:

> Time-zone rules, such as daylight savings, mean that not every local date-time is valid for the specified zone, thus the local date-time may be adjusted.

That method explains the rules used by java.time in making the necessary adjustments. Be sure to study them to understand the behavior.

The doc also says that rather than use the `ZonedDateTime.of` method, we should normally use the [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class to create a date-time from numbers. Then apply a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) by using a different [`ZonedDateTime.of`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#of-java.time.LocalDateTime-java.time.ZoneId-) static method.

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of( 2015, 9, 29, 10, 0, 0 );

ZoneId zoneId_LosAngeles = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
ZonedDateTime zdt_LosAngeles = ZonedDateTime.of( localDateTime, zoneId_LosAngeles ) ;
```

> zdt_LosAngeles : 2015-09-29T10:00-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

We can represent the very some moment in the timeline as seen in two other time zones. While [`America/Los_Angeles`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Los_Angeles) has standard & DST offsets of -08:00 & -07:00 respectively, [`America/Phoenix`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Arizona) (Arizona) has only -07:00, and [`America/Metlakatla`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Alaska) (Alaska) has only -08:00.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt_Phoenix = zdt_LosAngeles.withZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of( "America/Phoenix" ) );
ZonedDateTime zdt_Metlakatla = zdt_LosAngeles.withZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of("America/Metlakatla") );
```

> zdt_Phoenix : 2015-09-29T10:00-07:00[America/Phoenix]
>
> zdt_Metlakatla : 2015-09-29T09:00-08:00[America/Metlakatla]

The rules for adjusting for DST on “Spring Ahead” & “Fall Back” days are explained in the class doc.

> The local date-time is resolved to a single instant on the time-line. This is achieved by finding a valid offset from UTC/Greenwich for the local date-time as defined by the rules of the zone ID.
>
> In most cases, there is only one valid offset for a local date-time. In the case of an overlap, when clocks are set back, there are two valid offsets. This method uses the earlier offset typically corresponding to "summer".
>
> In the case of a gap, when clocks jump forward, there is no valid offset. Instead, the local date-time is adjusted to be later by the length of the gap. For a typical one hour daylight savings change, the local date-time will be moved one hour later into the offset typically corresponding to "summer".

### Joda-Time

If Java 8 technology in unavailable, use the third-party [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework (which inspired java.time). Joda-Time works in Android, by the way, with some special builds available from others helping overcome some issue with the Dalvik classloader.

### Avoid Old j.u.Date/Calendar

Avoid the old java.util.Date/.Calendar and java.text.SimpleDateFormat classes. These classes were a valiant industry-first attempt at handling date-time in a sophisticated manner. But ultimately they fail, proving to be confusing, troublesome, and flawed.

## ISO 8601

Both java.time and Joda-Time offer formatters that will generate string representations of your date-time values using those 3-4 letter codes if you must have them for output. But do not use them for data storage, data exchange, or parsing.

For those purposes learn about [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard string formats. Both java.time and Joda-Time use ISO 8601 by default when parsing and generating string representations.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. I am using java.time with `ZonedDateTime`s and a `DateTimeFormatter`. I use `Instant`s and add ranges using the `Duration.ofXXX()` methods before converting to `ZonedDateTime`s using `.atZone(ZoneId.of("time zone name"))`. Using the two/three letter abbreviations in displaying the time is a must though, as most of our typical end users would not understand the ISO 8601 format.

Comment: As I said, java.time provides formatters that produce those fake time zones in string representations. Use them if you must for presentation output to users. But keep them out of your head as a programmer. And don't expect to parse them; both java.time and Joda-Time refuse because of their ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Using `SimpleDateFormat` in Java, specifying either one seems to be valid.  When printed, you can see that the daylight savings time conversion takes place when it's parsed, even when `setLenient(false)` is called.

Example:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMMM dd HH:mm:ss z");
sdf.setLenient(false);
Date d = sdf.parse("2015 September 29 10:00:00 PST");
System.out.println(d);
```

This outputs:

```
Tue Sep 29 11:00:00 PDT 2015
```

It takes PST (Pacific Standard Time) and converts it to PDT (Pacific Daylight Time) upon output.  At least right now it does.  At the time of this writing, daylight savings time is in effect.

PDT is accepted also:

```
Date d2 = sdf.parse("2015 September 29 10:00:00 PDT");
System.out.println(d2);
```

This outputs:

```
Tue Sep 29 10:00:00 PDT 2015
```

Note: This is likely dependent on having a United States locale.  Since that is my default locale, the above works.  If that isn't your locale, try adding a second parameter `Locale.US` to the `SimpleDateFormat` constructor call at the top.

Comment: The behavior you describe only works because there are a handful of IDs that are recognized for backwards compatibility.  In general, you can't rely on parsing of time zone abbreviations. See the section titled "Three-letter time zone IDs" near the top of [the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html).  When parsing, the abbreviations that are recognized are the ones from RFC 822.  Others won't work.